# Can a unique index be created in MySQL if the table has repeating values?

Tags: mysql, database

For an existing table, is it permissible to create a unique on a column that might have repeating values?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it is not permissible.

The following SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE `table`
ADD UNIQUE (`column`)
```

Will generate the following error:

> #1062 - Duplicate entry 'data' for key 'column'

You can identify duplicates using:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
GROUP BY `column`
HAVING COUNT(`column`) > 1
```

After removing all of the duplicates, you can add the `UNIQUE` constraint.

Comment: Note - This will remove all records having that particular value. You just might want to delete all but one.

Answer (score 4):

Actually it is possible, at least in MySQL 5.1+.  You can use:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`column`);
```

If your table is InnoDB you will need to run this first:

```
set session old_alter_table=1
```

reference http://www.mikeperham.com/2012/03/02/deleting-duplicate-rows-in-mysql/

EDIT: As of MySQL 5.7.4, the IGNORE clause for ALTER TABLE is removed and its use produces an error.  Thanks to @EdwardvanKuik for Pointing it out in the comments

Comment: As of MySQL 5.7.4, the IGNORE clause for ALTER TABLE is removed and its use produces an error.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible:

```
Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry 'foo' for key 'index_clubs_on_url': CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_clubs_on_url` ON `clubs` (`url`)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible where any of the indexed columns in all repeat rows contain NULL because NULL is neither equal to nor not equal to NULL and hence the index values are not considered to be equal and are allowed to go ahead.

```
MariaDB [mydb]> select case when NULL = NULL OR NULL <> NULL then 'true' else 'false' end as 'test';
+-------+
| test  |
+-------+
| false |
+-------+
```

see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/156580) for example and (possible) workaround (where you are trying to enforce unique rows).

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.35-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```